# active record table not being updated properly but says it is in the console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am updating an active record table using this:

```
  def sort
    params[:piece].each_with_index do |id, index|
      current_user.lineup.piece_lineups.update_all({position: index+1}, {id: id})
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

everything looks like it's working except it's not actually saving the new sort order to the DB. looking at the output, it says it is updating everything properly. Here's the sql queries:

```
Started POST "/lineups/sort" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-26 08:07:24 -0700
Processing by LineupsController#sort as */*
  Parameters: {"piece"=>["1", "4", "2", "3", "7"]}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  Lineup Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `lineups`.* FROM `lineups` WHERE `lineups`.`user_id` = 3 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE `piece_lineups` SET `position` = 1 WHERE `piece_lineups`.`lineup_id` = 4 AND `piece_lineups`.`id` = 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE `piece_lineups` SET `position` = 2 WHERE `piece_lineups`.`lineup_id` = 4 AND `piece_lineups`.`id` = 4
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE `piece_lineups` SET `position` = 3 WHERE `piece_lineups`.`lineup_id` = 4 AND `piece_lineups`.`id` = 2
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE `piece_lineups` SET `position` = 4 WHERE `piece_lineups`.`lineup_id` = 4 AND `piece_lineups`.`id` = 3
  SQL (0.1ms)  UPDATE `piece_lineups` SET `position` = 5 WHERE `piece_lineups`.`lineup_id` = 4 AND `piece_lineups`.`id` = 7
  Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)
```

it seems like everything should be working but it isn't. what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my answer was wrong I think. Your code looks correct to me. I don't know why it is not working. But, I see that you are updating the piece record one by one, which is inefficient. It will generate O(n) sql update queries. Maybe you can try this, which will generate one update query:

```
attributes = Hash[params[:piece].each_with_index.map { |id, index| [id, {order: index}] }]
current_user.lineup.piece_lineups.update(attributes.keys, attributes.values)
```